# Access property of abstract superclass in matlab

Tags: matlab

please consider the following scenario:

I've got an abstract base class representing trackers. Each of these trackers is associated with a unique id.

```
classdef (Abstract) tracker
    properties (GetAccess=private)
        % id of this track
        id_ = -1;
    end

    methods
        % getter method
        function id = get.id_(obj)
            id = obj.id_;
        end
    end
end

classdef ct_tracker < tracker
    ...
end
```

My problem is, that I cannot access the id property from a subclass

```
ct_tracker_instance = ct_tracker()    
ct_tracker_instance.id
```

results in

> No appropriate method, property, or field id for class ct_tracker.

Comment: Is this not an access modifier problem? I'm not familiar with OOP in MATLAB but I know that in C# for example you would have to set your get function to be at least `protected` rather than `private`. I'm not sure if your `GetAccess=private` somehow applies to your `get` method as well...

Comment: Your property name is id_. If you access it you should get an error "You cannot get the 'id_' property of ct_tracker.". To get it outside class it needs to be 'public'. To get it only in sub-class you need 'protected' access. Name of output variable of get.id_ does not matter.

Answer (score 0):

Use `GetAccess=protected` instead. This allows subclasses to access the property. For more information on method attributes [see the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/method-attributes.html).